# Template template parameter on function

Tags: c++, templates

Is this valid template construct in C++ templates?

```
template < template <typename T2> class T> 
void foo() {

}
```

Comment: @ChrisLutz, I think `T2` is optional.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: I think, not really. http://ideone.com/8jlI5

Comment: @Nawaz - I remember reading that somewhere. I seem to just be wrong all over the place today. My bad.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. It is valid.

You can call this function with any class template which takes ***exactly*** one template parameter. For example,

```
template<typename T> 
struct A
{
   //...
};

foo< A >(); //ok
```

Note that you don't have to provide the template argument for `A` class template, which means, the following would result in compilation error:

```
foo< A<int> >(); //error
```

Also, in your code `T2` is optional, and in fact, you cannot use it in the function, so better remove it to make the definition simpler:

```
template < template <typename> class T> 
void foo() {

    T<int> x; //this is how T can be instantiated; provide template argument!
}
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/8jlI5

Comment: Like `T2` in this case, is it always optional? I couldn't make use of it on class templates either. http://ideone.com/LEt6N

Comment: @user974191: Yes. It is never required. You cannot use it in the template definition!