# Nested typenames in templates

Tags: c++, templates

I'd like to write a function template like that:

```
template< typename L<T> >  // does not work
void do_sth(L<T>& list){
    T value = 0;
    list.push_back(value);
}
```

This means, in the template I'd like to work with containers offering "push_back", but also with the type stored inside that container.

A workaround would be

```
template< typename T >
void do_sth(typename std::list<T>& list){
    T value = 0;
    list.push_back(value);
}

// call    
std::list<double> list;
do_sth<double>(list);
```

which is redundant because a) I already specified "double" when declaring "list" and b) the function would not work with a std::vector, although the implementation would perfectly fit.

Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

Comment: You mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782741/template-template-parameter-on-function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's one of the reasons STL containers provide the `value_type` typedef:

```
template< typename Container >
void do_sth(Container& list){
    typename Container::value_type value = 0;
    list.push_back(value);
}
```

Your workaround would also work with a plain call to `do_sth(list);` due to template argument deduction.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this :

```
template< typename T >
void do_sth( T & list){
    typename T::value_type value = 0;
    list.push_back(value);
}
```